# Activity restarted after orientation changed using fragments

Tags: android, fragment, orientation

In my application i created different folders (`layout-sw600dp and layout-sw600dp-land`)  for `portrait` and `landscape` for Tablets. And my activity contains 4 fragments. If i change orientation in 4th fragment, my activity restarted and it starts again from 1st fragment. But, it should show 4th fragment if orientation changed.

In my manifest file i am using the following, but its not working for fragments.

```
<activity
     android:name=".MyActivity"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
```

SO, Please guide me how solve this.

Comment: can you provide your code

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.mainscreen);
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new Fragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();

Comment: ok just add condition   setContentView(R.layout.mainscreen);  if(savedInstance == null ){getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new Fragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();}

Comment: thankyou for your answer. But its not working in my case.

Comment: add your full code in your question